# How to set standard login to local?

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain, local

I now have a computer with Windows 7 Operating system that used to be in a network. Now it's just a 'lonely' local computer.

I know there is the shortcut `.\User1` to log in quickly to local.

Is there anyway to set the local login as standard instead of having to use `.\` all the time?

Comment: Relevant: https://serverfault.com/questions/511317/hyper-v-server-cant-unjoin-an-orphaned-domain

Comment: Also relevant (linked from the ServerFault question above): https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/783802df-6c59-4665-9860-7e2d0720db4a/remove-and-join-a-domain-in-hyperv-server-2008-r2?forum=winserverhyperv

Comment: ´netdom remove´ seems only to work on a server, not the local computer

Comment: Relevant (may be considered 'duplicate'): https://serverfault.com/questions/699590/removing-a-computer-from-the-domain